# Relationship Between Rigid Body Colliisons and Animation Keyframes

Tags: physics

I am working on an animation consisting of a pool ball being struck by
a cue stick and then picked up by a mechanical mechanism. I get can the 
sequence of the collision and the animation of the crane to work. However, 
when I change the LOC/ROT of the crane keyframes, the cue ball jumps up and the 
collision no longer works. Not sure how they are related to fix. Thank You.

Comment: Did you make the cue stick to be a Rigid Body and did you check the Animated checkbox for the cue? I think you need to share the blend file.

Answer (score 1):

When you want an object to be handled by the physics sim, you must untick Animated.

You tick Animated when you want to take care of the object's animation by yourself, like when it's lifted by the crane.

You can also bake your physics animation to keyframes and delete the keyframes from when the crane takes over.